# PHP framework/CMS to use for website

Tags: php, cms

My website will consist of three(for now) different web apps built using Javascript and HTML Canvas. For the most part, the main interaction will be the API/AJAX calls made to the website from the javascript web apps. Aside from the web apps and the php pages that will handle the ajax requests, there will be areas that cover new products, and some other static pages, and a blog section.

I'm the PHP developer for this project and we haven't decided if we will separate the web apps, and the blogging/content portion of our website into two different websites or not.

I will need to build things like a user management/authentication/authorization system, tabular data info display on the web app users statistics and various other things like that.

What are some recommended PHP frameworks for a small project like this? We don't expect users to be massive. We aren't sure yet if we will use a CMS either.  One thing that's important is that the front end developers are using Sproutcore to build their web apps, and I'm still not sure yet how that will affect the decision of which framework/cms to use.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The [Choosing the right PHP framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838028/choosing-the-right-php-framework) topic at Stack Overflow may be of interest to you, however, this variety of question is being phased out; questions which solicit advice generally do not meet the guidelines outlined in our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq).